# How do I check in Python Selenium if a user is already registered? (Magento Cloud)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

**Initial situation:**

Currently I have defined several test cases in our project, including login and logout within a Magento cloud environment.

I currently used the Chrome Webdriver for this test.

Python and the latest Selenium version.

**Problem situation:**
I would like to check if a user is already registered.

**What I have so far:**

I'm currently checking whether a user wants to log in, and if it's the corresponding user "Frank" an assertion will be triggered.

But I believe that there are better solutions?

```
 def test_login(self):
        driver = self.driver 
        time.sleep(10) 
        driver.find_username = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//span[contains(text(), "Frank")]')))
        assert find_username
```

The question

Are there more sensible solutions how to query this within Python/Selenium?

Comment: do you want to verify that the error message DOES appear and DOES contain frank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Instead of using `presence_of_element_located()` you need to use **`visibility_of_element_located()`** and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def test_login(self):       
    try:
        driver.find_username = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//span[contains(., "Frank")]')))
        print("User was found")
        assert find_username
    except TimeoutException:
        print("User wasn't found")
```

Comment: Upvote the answer if this/any answer is helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.